# How to call Javascript __doPostBack from JSOUP

Tags: java, javascript, android, jsoup

I have a website that calls a __doPostBack for a specific link. I have tried loading the page that the link loads, but inputting POST data manually and also setting the __EVENTTARGET and __EVENTARGUMENT manually, but I keep receiving an error page.. If anyone has used the JSOUP library and has found a workaround for this problem please let me know. Here is the code for calling the website with POST data:

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("https://parentaccess.ocps.net/Progress/ProgressSummary.aspx?T=2").data(target.substring(0,target.length()-5)+"txtClass_DBID",dBID).data("__LASTFOCUS","").data("__EVENTVALIDATION", eventValidation).data("__VIEWSTATE", viewState).cookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", cookie).data("__EVENTTARGET",target).data("DropDownListGradingPeriod","3").data("__EVENTARGUMENT","").header("Content-Type","text/html; charset=utf-8").header("Connection", "keep-alive").header("Cache-Control", "private").method(Method.POST).execute();
                Document doc = res.parse();
                Document doc2 = Jsoup.connect("https://parentaccess.ocps.net/Progress/ProgressDetails.aspx").data(target.substring(0,target.length()-5)+"txtClass_DBID",dBID).data("__LASTFOCUS","").data("__EVENTVALIDATION", eventValidation).data("__VIEWSTATE", viewState).cookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", cookie).data("__EVENTTARGET",target).data("DropDownListGradingPeriod","3").data("__EVENTARGUMENT","").header("Content-Type","text/html; charset=utf-8").header("Connection", "keep-alive").header("Cache-Control", "private").get();
```

Please note that I have tried both the Connection.Response and the JSOUP.connect with POST data, but have been receiving errors for doc2 (res will load the page, but the information must not be passed because no table is generated with the given POST data). Thanks!

Comment: any luck solving this?

Comment: Unfortunately I was unable to solve this, I tried about everything but with no success

Answer (score 0):

Use HTMLUNIT for handling javascript.

Comment: Looks promising! I will try it as soon as possible and tell you how that goes :)

Comment: Hey, I tried this library with no success with Android. It will not let the project compile correctly.

Comment: @user1064249, HtmlUnit does not work with Android. Instead, you could find out where the `doPostBack()` request goes, and emulate it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

After spending few days the only solution what i found was htmlunit.

Here is the working code:

```
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("PAGE_URL");
InputStream inputStream = 
page.getElementById({EL_ID}").click().getWebResponse().getContentAsStream();
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("FILE_NAME"));
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
```